# How do I store the state of radio groups in React using react-hook-form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm using [react-hook-form](https://react-hook-form.com/) to store form data that is split into two pages as per the code seen on [Codesandbox.io](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-with-radio-buttons-whvf7). I am able to successfully store simple text inputs (like first name, email, etc) using property assignments like `defaultValue={state.data.firstName}` for example...but I can't figure out how to store the checked item in the radio group using the model suggested by react-hook-form. I've checked [their documentation](https://react-hook-form.com/api), and it's unfortunately sparse in mentioning radio button group state storage. Is this possible using their API?

```
import React from "react";
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { useStateMachine } from "little-state-machine";
import updateAction from "./updateAction";

const Step1 = props => {
  const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();
  const { action, state } = useStateMachine(updateAction);
  const onSubit = data => {
    action(data);
    props.history.push("./step2");
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubit)}>
      <h2>Step 1</h2>
      <label>
        First Name:
        <input
          name="firstName"
          ref={register}
          defaultValue={state.data.firstName}
        />
      </label>
      <label>
        Last Name:
        <input
          name="lastName"
          ref={register}
          defaultValue={state.data.lastName}
        />
      </label>

      <label className="control-label" htmlFor="vehicles">How many vehicles do you own?<br />
        <input type="radio" name="vehicles" id="vehicles-1" value="1"
          ref={register({ required: true })} className="radio" />
        <label class="radio">1</label>

        <input type="radio" name="vehicles" id="vehicles-2" value="2"
          ref={register({ required: true })} className="radio" />
        <label class="radio">2</label>
        {errors.vehicles && <div className="form_error">Number of Vehicles is required</div>}
      </label>

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
};

export default withRouter(Step1);
```

Thanks, in advance, for your help!

Comment: your example looks good to me, the radio button should work by default.

Comment: Notice how there is no `defaultValue={state.data.RADIOBUTTONVALUE)` in the radio input properties, unlike the firstName and lastName inputs where they have `defaultValue={state.data.lastName}` and `defaultValue={state.data.firstName}`? That's what I'm after...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are after this:

https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

```
<input type="radio" defaultChecked={state.data.checked === 'xxx'} />
```

Comment: Just wanted to provide [this link to the codesandbox page](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-hook-form-wizard-form-with-radio-buttons-whvf7) to those reading this answer (which has been updated with a  **working** example).